# Redux Form Values Properties Undefined & Refreshes on Submit

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-router, submit, redux-form

I am using redux-form in order to submit a new user signup page in my React Web App, but when I try to grab the input field values on the form of the parameter `values`, it comes back undefined in `mapDispatchToProps`. I have read many posts of people claiming their `values` variable comes back undefined, but that is not the case for me. Only when I `console.log(values.[inputName])` do I get undefined. According to the documentation, I cannot tell that I am doing anything incorrectly.

**Can someone please help determine what is causing `values.email` to be undefined?** Thanks.

```
// presentational component
class Signup extends Component {
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Signup</h1>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div>   
                        <label>
                            Email: 
                            <Field component="input" type="email" name="email" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>   
                        <label>
                            Password: 
                            <Field component="input" type="password" name="password" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'Signup',
    enableReinitialize: true
})(Signup)

// redux container component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleSubmit: (values) => {
            console.log(values.email); // outputs undefined!
        }
    };
}

const SignupContainer = connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Signup)

export default SignupContainer;


// reducer index.js
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

export const appReducer = combineReducers({
    form: formReducer
})


// store.js
export const store = createStore(
    appReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware
    )
);
```

#### Side Note

I have noticed that whenever I first click the submit button on the form, the page refreshes (so I do not see the console.log). All proceeding times does not cause a refresh, but I am unsure as to why. Any explanation of this would be greatly appreciated, too.

---

## Update

After changing my Router from HashHistory to BrowserRouter (react-router), the page refreshes *every* time I click submit. Seems that I have two problems now.

Comment: You have 2 password fields and no email field in your form...

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. That was a typo due to a copy/paste error, but my actual code has a separate email and password field. I have updated my post to indicate the more accurate code.